# Transfer GL Pixels into Camera pixels for broadcast

Tags: android, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0

I have got a plugin that streams camera, However I need to draw over this so which I am doing through openGLES2.0. I need to transfer the pixels from `GLES.ReadPixels()` combine it with camera pixels and then send it to the broadcaster I don't know in what kind of format android camera pixel bytes will be in or the GLPixel's format even so how do I write only the non transparent pixels from GLSurface to the camera bytes.